# How to call second function while first function is running, or vise versa?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Let's say I have two functions. One function will take a while to process, the other one is simple and runs quickly. I want to start them both at the same time, but have the simple one run continuously in a loop, which ends when the first function has completed. How can one do this?

```
## It will take a while to write out ##
function function_one()
 writedlm(big_array, "/very/large/file.csv") 
end

## trival function ##
function function_two()
 return 5
end

## I want to run something like this: ##
function call_both()
  while function_one()
    function_two()
  end
end

call_both()
```

I believe I need to set up a parallel process here, but I can't see how it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution using a global (but const for type-inference) variable:

```
const done_function_one = Ref{Bool}(false)

function call_both()
  done_function_one[] = false
  @sync begin
    @async begin
      function_one()
      done_function_one[] = true
    end
    @async begin
      while !done_function_one[]
        function_two()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

More compact implementation is possible, but the main idea is simple - use a global variable (sometimes called a *mutex*). Note `call_both` exits only after the little bit of `function_two` which is left (when `function_one` is done) had finished processing.